# Swapping images and captions at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, caption

I have a image gallery I am trying to make So far so good as it works fine. My problem is that no matter how I try, I cannot get each image to have its own caption when I swap them out using javascript. Now before anyone gets upset with me for this question, I have looked on here and found how some people add captions using html but when I swap the images taht wont work. I thought maybe create an empty div and insert the html text using javascript, but how can I get the caption to load that matches the appropriate pic? Is an array the only option here? Here is my page in question.

[My site](http://cisweb.bristolcc.edu/~rmailloux11/mm/Final/feat.html)

I leave the "photo" div empty so the image can load into it. So far everything works. Just confused on  the captioning.

Here is the javascript code

```
$('#gallery img').each(function(i) {
    var imgFile = $(this).attr('src');
    var preloadImage = new Image();
  var imgExt = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
  preloadImage.src = imgFile.replace(imgExt,'_h$1');

    $(this).hover(
        function() {
            $(this).attr('src', preloadImage.src);
        },
        function () {
        var currentSource=$(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src', imgFile);
    }); // end hover
}); // end each




$('#gallery a').click(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();   
var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
var oldImage = $('#photo img');
var newImage = $('<img src=" ' + imgPath + ' ">');
newImage.hide();
$('#photo').prepend(newImage);
newImage.fadeIn(1000);
oldImage.fadeOut(1000,function(){
$(this).remove();
});
});
$('#gallery a:first').click();
```

And my html

```
<div id="main">         <!-- Main Content -->

<div id="photo">
</div>

<div id="gallery">
<a href="images/home1_h.jpg"><img src="images/home1.jpg" alt="home 1"></a>
<a href="images/home2_h.jpg"><img src="images/home2.jpg" alt="home 2"></a>
<a href="images/home3_h.jpg"><img src="images/home3.jpg" alt="home 3"></a>
<a href="images/home4_h.jpg"><img src="images/home4.jpg" alt="home 4"></a>
<a href="images/home5_h.jpg"><img src="images/home5.jpg" alt="home 5"></a>
<a href="images/home6_h.jpg"><img src="images/home6.jpg" alt="home 6"></a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you create a fiddle so people can better help you..

Comment: what caption are you talking about ?

Comment: I dont have it in there yet but I want to add a caption to  the corresponding image in the "photo" div that loads when I click the thumbnail

Comment: Im just trying to figure out the technique or format I would use to do this. I was thinking maybe I could setup an array in my javascript, make each caption an array that loads using $(this)? I just imagined there must be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
$('#gallery img').click(function(evt) {  
    var elem = $(this);
    var oldImage = $('#photo img');
    $('#photo').prepend($('<img src=" ' + elem.attr('src') + ' ">').hide().fadeIn(1000));
    oldImage.fadeOut(1000,function(){
       $(this).remove();
       $("#caption").html(elem.attr('alt')); // set the caption
    });
});

$('#gallery img:first').trigger('click');
```

and as html

```
<div id="main">         <!-- Main Content -->

<div id="photo">
   <div style="text-align:center" id="caption"></div>
</div>

<div id="gallery">
    <img src="images/home1_h.jpg" alt="home 1">
    <img src="images/home2_h.jpg" alt="home 2">
    <img src="images/home3_h.jpg" alt="home 3">
    <img src="images/home4_h.jpg" alt="home 4">
    <img src="images/home5_h.jpg" alt="home 5">
    <img src="images/home6_h.jpg" alt="home 6">
 </div>

</div>
```

and a bit of css

```
#gallery img {
     opacity: 0.8;
     cursor: pointer;
}
#gallery img:hover {
     opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: Doesnt change the caption to match the image though so you cant have 6 diff captions

Comment: It does. It takes whatever is in `alt` attribute of the image and uses it as image caption